# constructor function objects

Tags: javascript, object, constructor

Ok So i am trying to create a constructor function that defines the
Circle class.

The class contains a single property named radius that is received as
an argument. The class has two methods: area which computes the area
of a circle, formula is radius*radius*3.14. diameter which computes the
diameter of a circle, formula is radius*2.

Prompt for a radius of a circle, and create an instance of the circle.
Display the result of the circle area method using document.write().
Display the result of the circle diameter method using
document.write(). Result for radius = 5; you may have slight
differences due to rounding.

circle area: 78.5 circle diameter: 10 Here's what I got but I've been
staring at this too long so I figured another set of eyes would help

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<head>
<script>

function radius(area,diameter)
{
this.area= radius * radius * 3.14;
this.diameter=radius * 2;
}
</head>
<body>
<script>
document.write(area);
document.write(diameter);
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: radius is referring to your function btw, multiplying it wont' work I don't think.

Comment: The function you posted isn't like what you describe above.

Comment: this appears to be homework. What have you tried?

Answer (score 0):

```
<html>
<head>
<script>
function circle(radius)
{
    this.radius = parseFloat(radius);
    this.diameter = radius*2.0;
    this.area = radius*radius*3.14;
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
<script>
    var a = new circle(5);
    document.write('diameter ' + a.diameter + '<br>');
    document.write('area ' + a.area + '<br>');
</script>
</body>
</html>
```